# I developed an android application with cordova and I want to convert it to iOS as well

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I developed an android application with cordova and I want to convert it to iOS as well. Before starting my project I heard that we are able to convert same project with multiple platforms using cordova. But now I don't know how to convert my project to IOS. Can any one suggest good tutorial OR examples to do it.

And also mention what are all prerequisites to convert my android application to IOS using phone gap.

Suggest me some tutorials with examples.

Comment: I developed an android application with cordova and I want to convert it to iOS

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need an actual **Mac** computer. I suggest a MacBook Air, as they are cheaper than an iPhone. Then purchase an Apple developer **license** (USD 100/year) if you plan to submit this app to the App Store. Finally, you can migrate your Cordova source code to Xcode to compile the iOS version as explained in this guide:

[Build Cordova iOS app from Visual Studio for Windows](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/)

The artice explains how to create a new app in **Xcode** and then export your source code from the Windows PC to the Mac. You can safely ignore all references to Visual Studio if you aren't using it, because it's not needed: Just follow the steps from the ***For your iOS app*** section.

[image]

Comment: It is free to build and run iOS apps on your personal devices. You don’t need to spend money on an Apple developer account until you want to submit to the app store

Comment: That is correct, I have edited the post to reflect that